# How to import List from typing module to recognize the type List[int] in Class?

Tags: python-3.x, list, types, importerror

While running my python3 code, I am getting the below error:

> 'TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable'

System unable to recognize typing module having List parameter while I am trying to set `__init__ class`  argument as `List[int]`

I had installed `typing.py` module via `pip` and trying to `import typing`

Even then system not recognizing `List[int]` type in the Class definition.

Below is the code for the same,

```
from typing import List
class newcls:
    def __init__(self, a: int,arr: list[int]):
        self.a=a
        self.arr=arr
    def new1(self):
        print('a=',self.a)
        print(self.arr)
obj1=newcls(1,[1,2,3])
obj1.new1()
```

And the error message I get on running,

> Runtime error as def **init**(self, a: int,arr: list[int]):
>
> TypeError:'type' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo in your code. The signature of your `__init__` function should read:

```py
def __init__(self, a: int,arr: List[int]):
```

(note the upper case `List`, not the built-in type `list`)

Comment: i tried already def __init__(self, a: int, b: int, arr: list[int]):
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: But you still use `list`? It has to be `List`, with upper-case L.

Comment: First I tried import typing
class newcls:
    def __init__(self, a: int,arr: List[int]):
        self.a = a
        self.arr=arr
    def prt(self):
        print(self.a)
        print(self.arr)
obj1=newcls(1,[0,1,2])
obj1.prt()

Comment: def __init__(self, a: int,arr: List[int]):
NameError: name 'List' is not defined

Comment: Then I tried lower case as well.I knew where exactly the problem. But i dont know how to rectify. Problem is due to command import typing. Code is not recognizing typing.py file where  all hint type exist . I already pip installed , even then no use.

Comment: Inporting typing works fine, otherwise you would get an ImportError. Read your error messages, in your latest one you just imported typing, not List. It has to be `from typing import List`, then use `List` in your type signature. If that doesn’t work please update your question with the exact error and everything you tried.

Comment: list - arr -  accepting any values other than integer even after defining List as List[int] from typing import *
class newcls:
    print('new cls module')
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int, arr: List[int]):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.arr=arr
        print('type of list',type(arr))  output as      :  type of list <class 'list'>
a= 1
b= 2
list = ['5', 'name', 3]

Comment: Please inform yourself about Python type hints. They are *not* enforced at runtime, so *you* have to make sure to pass the right type. Type hints are mostly to tell other people what they should pass, it never limits what can be passed. It seems to me that the original problem was resolved; please ask a new question if you want to know more about type hints and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

BTW this is a solution to twoSum problem from leetcode

```
from typing import List
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, numbers: List[int], target:int) -> List[int]:
        """
        :type numbers: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        l, r = 0 , len(numbers) - 1
        while l < r:
            curSum = numbers[l] + numbers[r]
            
            if curSum > target:
                r-=1
            elif curSum < target:
                l+=1
            else:
                return [l+1, r+1]

instance = Solution()
print(instance.twoSum([2,7,11,15], 9)) # returns [1,2]
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.8.0

Comment: Your leetcode solution only works if you assume that the input array is sorted. It **won't** work for an input like: `print(instance.twoSum([2,8,7,6], 9))`.

Answer (score 0):

One can go along the lines if working with Dataframes:

```
from typing import List, Type

class someclass():

   def __init__(self, dataframe: List[Type[DataFrame]]) -> None:
```

or Classes:

```
class Base:
  pass

def sub_classes() -> List[Type[Base]]
```